# Is there a way a normal user can view very old Wikipedia articles?

Tags: wikipedia

There is a deleted Wikipedia article I'm trying to see. It's not on the Wayback Machine or archive.is, and it was deleted 2006, before Deletionpedia started, so I can't find it there. Is there any sort of way I could find a copy of it, other than being an administrator or some sort of special user on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would simply ask the administrators to send it by e-mail, for example. If you explain to them why you need it and they don't find it against any rule, then they can look at the deleted version and send it to you, for example by e-mail. It is best to submit a request on the [administrator's message board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Administrators%27_noticeboard).

Definitely don't put your email on that page, but connect it to your account.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a very very old article, you could try [Nostalgia Wikipedia](https://nostalgia.wikipedia.org/).